# Restricting a GUI user to perform only predefined actions on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, privileges, guest-account

I am the admin of an Ubuntu machine, which I want to let a user "guest" login to via GUI.  This user should be able to perform only certain actions (like view the contents of some files located on the desktop etc), and Shutdown / Reboot. Nothing else. How can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how multiuser systems are supposed to work. Don't make them an administrator and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `chroot`, which restricts a process (like the top process of a logged-in user) to a certain subdirectory tree (also called "chroot jail"). This subdirectory tree will a need a copy/link of every file, library, and application the user needs. Conversely, the user cannot access anything that is not in this subdirectory tree.

There are tutorials how to set this up on Ubuntu, e.g. [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/use-chroot-for-testing-on-ubuntu/) (first Google result, there are plenty more).

If you want a GUI login to land in a chroot jail, you'll have to modify the login process for that particular user in your Display Manager configuration (I guess that's `gdm` or `kdm` on Ubuntu, but I haven't used Ubuntu for some time).